# How to order users alphabetically by name? in plugin UPME

Tags: plugins, php, search, users, wp-user-query

### I have this code:

```
<?php
  class UPME_List_Cards {

  public $upme_options;


  public function __construct() {
    global $upme;
    add_shortcode('upme_latest_members_list', array($this,'latest_members_list'));
}

public function latest_members_list($atts){
    global $upme_template_loader,$upme_list_card_params;
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'limit'   => 10 ,
        'user_role' => '',
        'template' => 'members_icon_mini',
      ), $atts ) );

    $admin_users = get_users('role=administrator&orderby=registered&order=DESC');
    $admin_users_list = array();
    foreach ($admin_users as $admin_user) {
        array_push($admin_users_list,$admin_user->ID);
    }

    $display = '';

    $args = array(
                'exclude'=> $admin_users_list,
                'number' => $limit,
                'orderby' => 'registered',
                'order'   => 'desc',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    0 => array(
                        'key'     => 'upme_user_profile_status',
                        'value'   => 'ACTIVE',
                        'compare' => '='
                        ),
                    1 => array(
                        'key'     => 'upme_approval_status',
                        'value'   => 'ACTIVE',
                        'compare' => '='
                        ),
                    2 => array(
                        'key'     => 'upme_activation_status',
                        'value'   => 'ACTIVE',
                        'compare' => '='
                        )
                )
            );

    if($user_role != ''){
        $args['role'] = $user_role;
    }

    $users_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
    $results = $users_query->get_results();
    $upme_list_card_params['results'] = $results;

    ob_start();

    switch($template){
        case 'members_icon_mini':                
            $upme_list_card_params['css_class'] = 'upme-list-card-default-mini';
            $upme_template_loader->get_template_part('members-icon-mini');        
            break;

        case 'members_icon_mini_rounded':                
            $upme_list_card_params['css_class'] = 'upme-list-card-default-mini-rounded';
            $upme_template_loader->get_template_part('members-icon-mini');        
            break;
    }

    $display = ob_get_clean();

    return $display;       
}

}

$upme_list_cards = new UPME_List_Cards();
```

So, how to order user alphabetically by name in UPME plugin?

Comment: Hello @Diana - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Unfortunately, questions regarding 3rd-party products are considered [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here as they require extremely intimate knowledge of extremely specialized code in order to answer well. Your question would be best addressed in the 3rd-party's official support channels. Please review the "[ask]" page in our [help] for more information about what constitutes a good question for our community.

Comment: @bosco It's a `get_users()` and `WP_User_Query` call…

Comment: @kaiser aye it is! I was only commenting on the appropriateness of the content: the question, both in title and one-sentence body paraphrasing the title, specifically addresses a [proprietary 3rd-party plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/user-profiles-made-easy-wordpress-plugin/4109874). Beyond that, the vast majority of the question is comprised of a portion of that premium plugin's codebase, which seems as though it might violate licensing terms. This question is significantly disparate from *"how can I sort users alphabetically"*, in my mind.

Comment: I guess I didn't really phrase that properly in my original comment... I admit it was something of a canned response - my apologies =/

Answer (score 0):

Diana you must change line of code in this array

```
 $args = array(
                'exclude'=> $admin_users_list,
                'number' => $limit,
                'orderby' => 'registered',
                'order'   => 'desc',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    0 => array(
                        'key'     => 'upme_user_profile_status',
                        'value'   => 'ACTIVE',
                        'compare' => '='
                        ),
                    1 => array(
                        'key'     => 'upme_approval_status',
                        'value'   => 'ACTIVE',
                        'compare' => '='
                        ),
                    2 => array(
                        'key'     => 'upme_activation_status',
                        'value'   => 'ACTIVE',
                        'compare' => '='
                        )
                )
            );
```

This line `'orderby' => 'registered',` you will change registerd to `'name'` so this line would look like this `'orderby' => 'name',` and also change this line from desc to asc `'order'   => 'desc',` change it to `'order'   => 'asc',`.

Comment: actually i change the lines that you say, but doesn't work